# How to find out leading research articles in a specific area?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, advice, research

If one needs to find out the leading research articles and most cited or influential research articles in a specific area of mathematics, let's say, fractals, chaos and non-linear dynamics what that person should do?

Comment: Find some experts to talk to.....

Comment: It seems to me that if you're trying to get a foot-hold into some area of mathematics, you probably don't want leading (or influential) research articles. Instead, you want survey articles and expository articles.

Answer (score 2):

[Google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/) is very useful for this.  It tells you the citation count for each paper, and has useful "cited by" and "related article" links.

Also, when you find a relevant paper, read the related work section in the introduction.  Often that is a useful guide to the literature.